# Investigate MDX DistinctCount discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, ssas, distinct, mdx, olap

When I run this:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT AS  
DISTINCTCOUNT([Student Term].[Student ID].MEMBERS)
SELECT {MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT} ON 0  ,
[Student Term].[Term Code].&[1151] on 1
FROM [Enrollment]
```

I get a student count that agrees with the following sql (I'll refer to this correct count as "count A"):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([student_id])) 
FROM  dbo.Fact_Enrollments 
WHERE Term_Code = '1151'
```

but unfortunately when I run this MDX (using a different but similar dimension) I get a different count that is less than "count A":

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT AS  
DISTINCTCOUNT([Student Term].[Student ID].MEMBERS)
SELECT {MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT} ON 0  ,
[Term].[Term Type].[Academic Term].&[1151] ON 1
FROM [Enrollment]
```

---

I am not sure how to figure out what is going wrong in the second mdx query (more directly, what is going wrong in that "Term" dimesion).  At first I thought maybe the Dim_Term table wasn't completely joining to the fact table (Fact_Enrollments) but this query which joins the two, does return "count A" (the correct count):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([student_id]))
 FROM dbo.Fact_Enrollments
INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Term ON Acad_Term_Cd=Term_Code
 WHERE Acad_Term_Cd = '1151'
```

I thought that maybe the best way to see what is going on is to find a list of all the distinct Student IDs that went into the first count and then do the same for the second count and take a deeper look at those in the first list but not the second but I do not know how to determine what the student IDs are that lead to the CountDistinct results that I am seeing.

I have tried a couple things beyond what I am writing here (left out because this is already pretty long) but I keep coming up with "count A" as my total result.

How can I find the list of distinct members that are counted by a DistinctCount call?

(or, alternatively what is the best way to discover the cause of this discrepancy)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your relationships are messed up.

There is an important thing you should know. `DISTINCTCOUNT` is actually `Count of distinct NON-EMPTY`.

[DistinctCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492142.aspx)

Instead of the second query, try the below:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT AS  
COUNT(DISTINCT([Student Term].[Student ID].MEMBERS))
SELECT {MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT} ON 0  ,
[Term].[Term Type].[Academic Term].&[1151] ON 1
FROM [Enrollment]
```

This counts the empty cells too and thus should return a bigger value.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The MDX you suggested returns the count of all unique student ids (irrespective of those that have records in academic term "1151") but what I want is a count of all the unique student ids in "Fact_Enrollments" where Acad_Term_Cd  (from the Dim_Term table joined by acad_term_cd=term_code) is '1151' (the second bit of SQL in my original post).

Comment: In response to your guess that the relationships are messed up, here is what I have: in the Data Source View, there is one relationship between the Fact_Enrollments and Dim_Term tables...where Fact_Enrollments.Term_Code (foreign key table)=Dim_Term.Acad_Term_Cd (primary key table).  There are no nulls and no blanks in either of these columns and every value in Fact_Enrollments.Term_Code is found in Dim_Term.Acad_Term_Cd (which is unique).  Is there another relationship somewhere else I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

As a slight tweak to Sourav's script please add the `EXISTING` keyword:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT AS  
  COUNT(DISTINCT(EXISTING [Student Term].[Student ID].MEMBERS))
SELECT 
  {MEASURES.SETDISTINCTCOUNT} ON 0  ,
  [Term].[Term Type].[Academic Term].&[1151] ON 1
FROM [Enrollment];
```